# How can I control when Microsoft Security Essentials Updates Itself?

Tags: anti-virus

I'm using Microsoft Security Essentials (MSE) on a Windows Vista SP2 box.  Every day in the 4 PM hour MSE updates itself: The green fortress icon in the notification area displays an animated download arrow, and my computer becomes unusably sluggish for five minutes (or more).  I'm generally forced to take a coffee break or read a magazine.

How can I control the time of day when this update occurs? Sometime after 9 PM would be ideal.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can change the time:

> Updates are a once per 24 hour check on a schedule determined by MSE. There is no setting within MSE to change the scheduled time or frequency.

[Source](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/mseupdate/thread/74e507b8-f6da-4eca-8ce7-d1aca7d3f1ba)

Comment: Thanks.  Argh. The next sentence might provide a workaround, though: "Optionally, you can add a check for updates by setting check for updates before scan and setting up a scheduled scan daily (for a time when the PC will be on as it won't run a missed scan later)." I'll see if that works.

Comment: And ... it doesn't work. I set it to do a Quick Scan at 2 AM daily, and to check for updates before running the scan.  It completed the scan at 2:21 AM today, but it's 4:20 PM and MSE has decided to update itself, right on its inconvenient schedule. Oh well.